# Stopping all animation upon click-through in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, ads, banner

In AS2, I would just add a stop(); into the clickTag, but I'm not sure how I would do so in AS3.

Here's a sample code of my clickTag

```
package 
{
import com.greensock.*;
import com.greensock.easing.*;

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.net.navigateToURL;

public class main300x250 extends MovieClip
{
public var paramList:Object;

    public function main300x250()
    {
        addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

    }

    private function init(e:Event):void
    {
        removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        myBTN.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler);
        myBTN.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, clickOver);
        myBTN.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, clickOut);


        TweenNano.from( t1, .5, {alpha:0, scaleX:0, scaleY:0, ease:Back.easeOut, delay:0});
        TweenNano.to( t1, .5, {scaleX:0, scaleY:0, ease:Back.easeIn, delay:1.75});

        TweenNano.from( f2.a, .35, {y:"+35", alpha:0, delay:2.25});
        TweenNano.from( f2.b, .35, {y:"+35", alpha:0, delay:2.4});
        TweenNano.from( f2.nugsL, .5, {x:"-200", ease:Quad.easeIn, delay:2.75});
        TweenNano.from( f2.nugsR, .5, {x:"+200", ease:Quad.easeIn, delay:3.15});

        TweenNano.to( f2.a, .25, {y:"+15", alpha:0, delay:5.5});
        TweenNano.to( f2.b, .25, {y:"+15", alpha:0, delay:5.65});

        TweenNano.from( f3.a, .35, {y:"+35", alpha:0, delay:5.75});
        TweenNano.to( f2.nugsL, .5, {x:6.5, y:30.5, ease:Quad.easeIn, delay:6.2});
        TweenNano.to( f2.nugsR, .5, {x:6.5, y:30.5, ease:Quad.easeIn, delay:6.2});
        TweenNano.from( f3.d, .5, {x:"-20", y:"+20", alpha:0, delay:6.6});

        TweenNano.to( f3.a, .25, {y:"+15", alpha:0, delay:8.75});
        TweenNano.to( f2.nugsL, .25, {x:"+350", delay:8.9});
        TweenNano.to( f2.nugsR, .25, {x:"+350", delay:8.9});
        TweenNano.to( f3.d, .15, {alpha:0, delay:9});           

        TweenNano.from(t2, 0.65, {delay:9.15, y:'+='+250, ease:Back.easeOut});

        TweenNano.from(t2.a, 0.2, {delay:9.25, y:'+='+75});
        TweenNano.from(t2.b, 0.2, {delay:9.45, y:'+='+75});
        TweenNano.from(t2.c, 0.2, {delay:9.45, y:'+='+75});

        TweenNano.to(t2.b, 0.25, {delay:10.2, x:"-30"});
        TweenNano.to(t2.c, 0.25, {delay:10.2, x:"-30"});
        TweenNano.to(t2.d, 0.25, {delay:10.2, alpha:1, x:"+31"});

        TweenNano.to(endLockUp, 1, {delay:10.2, scaleX:1.15, scaleY:1.15, ease:Quad.easeIn});
        TweenNano.from(endLockUp.a, 0.2, {delay:10.2, y:"+200"});
        TweenNano.from(endLockUp.b, 0.2, {delay:10.4, x:"-200"});
        TweenNano.from(endLockUp.c, 0.2, {delay:10.4, x:"+200"});
        TweenNano.from(endLockUp.d, 0.2, {delay:10.6, x:"-200"});
        TweenNano.from(endLockUp.e, 0.2, {delay:10.6, x:"+200"});
        TweenNano.from(endLockUp.f, 0.2, {delay:10.8, x:"-200"});
        TweenNano.from(endLockUp.g, 0.2, {delay:10.8, x:"+200"});
        TweenNano.from(endLockUp.h, 0.2, {delay:11, x:"-120"});
        TweenNano.from(endLockUp.i, 0.2, {delay:11, x:"+120"});
        TweenNano.to(endLockUp, 0.2, {delay:11.2, scaleX:1, scaleY:1});


        TweenNano.from( cta, .5, {y:"+200", ease:Back.easeOut, delay:11.4});

        TweenNano.from( logo, .15, {y:-62.65 , delay:11.85});
        TweenNano.from( legal, .1, {alpha:0, delay:11.9});



    }

    private function clickOver(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        TweenNano.to( cta, .25, {scaleX:1.15, scaleY:1.15});
    }

    private function clickOut(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        TweenNano.to( cta, .25, {scaleX:1, scaleY:1});
    }

    function clickHandler(e:MouseEvent):void {
        var click_url:String = root.loaderInfo.parameters.clickTAG;
        if(click_url) {
        navigateToURL(new URLRequest(click_url), '_blank');
        TweenNano.stop();
                        }
            }


        }

 }
```

The animation is nested into another .as file
Edit: pasted entire .as file code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This stops all animation:

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.DisplayObject;
    public function stop_animation(object:Object, checker:Function=null):void
    {
        if (checker != null)
        {
            if(!checker(object))
                return;
        }   
        if(!object)
            return;
        if(object as MovieClip)
            object.gotoAndStop(object.currentFrame);
        if(!object.hasOwnProperty("numChildren")||(! object as DisplayObject))
            return;
        for(var i:int=0;i<object.numChildren;++i)
            stop_animation(object.getChildAt(i));
    }
}
```

This stops all animation, which is under position of the mouse click:
**EDIT: Actually, it doesn't when clips are nested**

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.DisplayObject;

    public function stop_animation(object:Object, stage:*, checker:Function=null):void
    {
        if (checker != null)
        {
            if(!checker(object))
                return;
        }   
        if(!object)
            return;
        if(object as MovieClip)
            if(object.hitTestPoint(stage.mouseX,stage.mouseY))
                object.gotoAndStop(object.currentFrame);
        if(!object.hasOwnProperty("numChildren")||(! object as DisplayObject))
            return;
        for(var i:int=0;i<object.numChildren;++i)
            stop_animation(object.getChildAt(i),stage);
    }
}
```

and can be called like: stop_animation(this,stage); 
If you pass a checker function, all objects for which it returns false will be excluded from applying the functions.

---

This probably won't do with arrays, Dictionaries and etc., but you can iterate through them and call it from current element. (Supposing, that they have no inner arrays/dictionaries)

---

Code that should stop greensock animation:

```
    package 
{
    import flash.events.Event;
    import com.greensock.*;
    import com.greensock.easing.*;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    public class main extends MovieClip
    {
        var is_stopped:Boolean=false;

        var tweens:Array=new Array();
        public function main()
        {
            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,setup);
            addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, clickHandler);
        }
        public function setup(e:Event):void
        {
            tweens.push(TweenNano.from( t1, .5, {alpha:0, scaleX:0, scaleY:0, ease:Back.easeOut, delay:0}));
            tweens.push((TweenNano.to( t1, .5, {scaleX:0, scaleY:0, ease:Back.easeIn, delay:1.75})));

        }
        public function clickHandler(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            trace("!");
            is_stopped=true;
            t1.stop();
            for(var i in tweens)
            {
                tweens[i].kill();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`CLICK` sometimes behaves incorrectly, so I replaced it with `DOWN`

Comment: What do you pass as object?

Comment: It should be movieclip you want to stop or its parent. Or you don't have a reference to such clips?

Comment: The animations are utilized in greensock, so in the code you will see the TweenNano portion that utilizes the animation. Sorry, I'm not very experienced with Flash overall. If it helps, I want to stop all animations at the entire frame that a click is made.

Comment: I added new code. It stops animation, at least in file I created

Comment: There is no need in is_stopped. It is from an earlier attempt.

Comment: I am not sure where to add that in my code as it seems to have taken away my clickTag

Comment: Add all your TweenNano from and to to array tweens,as in this code. In click tag function `for(var i in tweens){tweens[i].kill();}` Besides, use `stop()` on each of your clips: t1, t2, logo, etc.

Comment: I am getting error 1120: Access of undefined property tweens.